# pg_dump to Remote Server?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Is it possible to use `pg_dump` to backup to another server on the LAN?

```
pg_dump -U username dbname > rich@workstation.local/users/rich/pg_backups/bkup-dbname.sql
```

So from a server to rich's workstation pg_backups directory?  Is this doable or does rich need to pull the backup from his workstation?

Comment: you could *instead* pull from the remote. (iff you have pg_dump installed there)

Comment: Is that the only option?  It's not possible to push files across the LAN?

Comment: You could pipe the output into a scp command

Comment: related article with multiple local/remote scenarios: https://momjian.us/main/blogs/pgblog/2018.html#September_12_2018

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this and here are a couple. Assuming you have ssh access to the remote host:

```
pg_dump -Fc myDb |ssh remoteHost 'cat >/tmp/dumpOfMyDb'
```

If you have the remote host mounted as an NFS share on your localhost, then you can just run:

```
pg_dump -d myDb -Fc -f /path/to/nfs/mount
```

Tip: -Fc has compression enabled.